Cors issue with ASP.NET Web API on .NET 4.8 "It does not have HTTP ok status"
My scenario is
A website (located at https://xxx.crm4.dynamics.com) needs to call a Web API (on .NET 4.8) that is hosted on a server inside a network. The call to the Web API is made by Javascript code.
The user browsing the website will always be inside the network that the Web API is hosted in.
At first I ran into some basic, CORS related, issues caused by the Web API simply not being configured to allow CORS. I solved them but cannot get passed the following error displayed in browser when calling the Web API.
Error details

Access to XMLHttpRequest at x1 from origin x2 has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

When I check Chrome Network tab to inspect the call I can see the following under tab "Headers", section "General":
Request URL: https://xxxxx.xx.xxx.xx:8053/api/account/Createsomething?id=123}
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 10.125.3.182:8053
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

What I have done so far to the Web API to try to get CORS fully working is:
web.config:
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="https://xxx.crm4.dynamics.com" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="*" />
  </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>

<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>

I've also tried adding the following function to Global.asax, as per a recommendation I read about, but with no result:
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (HttpContext.Current.Request.HttpMethod == "OPTIONS")
     {
         HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
     }
}

On the IIS website I've configured the following:
Anonymous Authentication = Enabled
Windows Authentication = Enabled
ASP.NET Impersonation = Enabled

As for "Authorization Rules" I'm allowing "Anonymous Users" when using the OPTIONS verb because that's what I had to do to get past the CORS issue on another website where we ran into the same issue. That website is hosted on the same server but build on .NET 8.0.
The Web API function is working as expected when called using Insomnia/Postman so there is no issue with the functionality of the function itself.
Any suggestions on what to try next would be greatly appreciated!
